# An email subscription form with Django and Mailchimp doesn't work after deployment (DigitalOcean)

Tags: python, django, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I've built a simple email subscription form with Django and Mailchimp. It works perfectly fine locally, however, after deploying it to DigitalOcean it doesn't seem to work. I thought it might be related to the database, but I did migrate on the server and haven't received any errors (using Ubuntu 20.04 on the server).

Hope someone has a clue and could assist me with this issue.

Here is the form:
https://www.winoutt.io

views.py

```py
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

# from django.conf import settings
from .models import Signup
from decouple import config

import json
import requests


# MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = settings.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY
# MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER = settings.MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER
# MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID = settings.MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID


MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = config("MAILCHIMP_API_KEY")
MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER = config("MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER")
MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID = config("MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID")

api_url = f"https://{MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0"
members_endpoint = f"{api_url}/lists/{MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID}/members"


def subscribe_email(email):
    data = {"email_address": email, "status": "subscribed"}
    req = requests.post(
        members_endpoint, auth=("", MAILCHIMP_API_KEY), data=json.dumps(data)
    )
    return req.status_code, req.json()


def newsletter_email_list(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST.get("email", None)
        email_query = Signup.objects.filter(email=email)

        if email:
            if email_query.exists():
                messages.info(request, "You are already on the waitlist.")
            else:
                try:
                    subscribe_email(email)
                    subscribed = Signup.objects.create(email=email)
                    subscribed.save()
                    messages.success(
                        request,
                        "Thank you! We're putting you on the waitlist. Bear with us.",
                    )
                except:
                    messages.warning(request, "Something went wrong. Please try again.")
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER"))
        else:
            messages.warning(request, "Please enter your email")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER"))

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER"))
```

models.py

```py
from django.db import models


class Signup(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

urls.py

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from pages.views import custom_page_not_found_view, PageView
from about.views import AboutView
from privacy.views import PrivacyView
from newsletter.views import newsletter_email_list


handler404 = "pages.views.custom_page_not_found_view"

urlpatterns = [
    path("jet/", include("jet.urls", "jet")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", PageView.as_view(), name="all_pages"),
    # path("<slug>/", PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post_detail"),
    path("tinymce/", include("tinymce.urls")),
    path("about/", AboutView.as_view(), name="about"),
    path("privacy-policy/", PrivacyView.as_view(), name="privacy"),
    path("newsletter/subscribe/", newsletter_email_list, name="newsletter_subscribe"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

template

```html
<form action="{% url 'newsletter_subscribe' %}" class="flex items-end justify-center w-full mt-4" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="w-full px-3 py-1 mt-2 text-base leading-8 text-gray-100 transition-colors duration-200 ease-in-out border border-gray-700 rounded outline-none bg-blackLight focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Your email" value="{{ email }}" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="inline-flex px-8 py-2 mt-4 mb-12 ml-4 text-lg text-white bg-blue-600 border-0 border-transparent rounded-lg shadow focus:outline-none hover:bg-blue-700" value="Send">Join</button>
    </form>
```

.env

```
# Database Configurations
DB_ENGINE="django.db.backends.postgresql"
DB_NAME=""
DB_USER=""
DB_PASSWORD=""
DB_HOST="localhost"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it was a permission matter. However, I solved this issue by editing gunicorn.service file.

I opened gunicorn.service file

```sh
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service
```

BEFORE editing

```sh
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=djangoadmin
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/djangoadmin/canny
ExecStart=/home/djangoadmin/.local/share/virtualenvs/canny-9cyzXi2O/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          config.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

AFTER editing

```sh
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=djangoadmin
Group=djangoadmin
WorkingDirectory=/home/djangoadmin/canny
ExecStart=/home/djangoadmin/.local/share/virtualenvs/canny-9cyzXi2O/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          config.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I merely changed the Group section so it will match my User.

It did the trick.

Comment: I also generated a new API key only for production usage.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a database on DigitalOcean? If you were hosting a local database, you'll need to either change to a sqlite backend, or attach to a cloud RDBMS.

Comment: I used postgresql locally and have created a new one for production on DigitalOcean.